# gruntjs: strategy to modify a file more than once using several tasks

Tags: javascript, css, workflow, less, gruntjs

What is your strategy for the following scenario:

I have: app/demo.less

I want: dist/demo.css

Inbetween I want:

- do some search/replace using regexp
- add vendor-prefixes automatically
- want to compile to less

For every single step it is easy to define source and destination.

1. But how do you work? Do you create a file for every intermediate step and name it properly?
2. Do you create a file in dist in the first step and change inplace afterwards?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say 2 is the best approach. Depending on what the regex is doing you may want to do this first, but I would say to process your LESS into CSS, then do search and replace, then add your vendor prefixes automatically. There's no real sense to generate intermediary files as you'll most likely need to remove them afterwards; unless you are doing so for debugging purposes.

You'll find that these three tasks do exactly what you need:

1. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less
2. https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer
3. https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace

Comment: Thank you for the first part of your answer. The second part (naming tasks) was already clear and just an example for different file modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the `build` task for something like [the Yeoman generator for Angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/c4dfd61d860f86a97026d1e5188ab78a87f4e6a1/templates/common/Gruntfile.js). The pattern across filetypes seems to be generating new files for `/dist` in the first task, and then modifying them in place.